# Determine if $f_n(x)=\frac {2nx^2}{n^2x^4 +1} $ converges pointwise or/and uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> Determine if $f_n(x)=\frac {2nx^2}{n^2x^4 +1}$ converges pointwise or/and uniformly ?

For pointwise convergence,$ \forall x\in \mathbb R ,\forall \epsilon \gt0\qquad$
I should pick an $N \in \mathbb N \qquad$ such that $n\geq N \qquad$ implies $ |f_n(x)-f(x)|\lt \epsilon $

For determining $N$ , here is my scratch:

$f(x)=lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\frac {2nx^2}{n^2x^4 +1}=0$

Want $N$ s.t $n\geq N $ implies $|\frac {2nx^2}{n^2x^4 +1}-0|\lt\epsilon$

$\frac {nx^2}{n^2x^4 +1}\lt \frac {2nx^2}{n^2x^4 +1}=|\frac {2nx^2}{n^2x^4 +1}-0|\lt\epsilon$

Now, $n\geq N \iff \frac 1 n \leq \frac 1 N \iff \frac {nx^2}{n^2x^2}\leq \frac 1N $

So, $\frac {nx^2}{n^2x^2+1}\lt \frac 1N $
Then now what should I choose $N $ ?

Comment: Uniform convergence on what set?

Comment: It's not written but I suppose it's on reals

Comment: converges to  zero pointwise but not uniform over $R$ since the supremum of $f_n$  goes to infinity as n goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence converges point-wise to $0$.

$$\frac{2nx^2}{n^2 x^4+1}  \le \frac{2nx^2}{n^2 x^4}= \frac{2}{nx^2} < \epsilon$$
Now for a fixed $x$ choose $n> \frac{2}{\epsilon x^2 }$.

Assume for contradiction that $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$  converges uniformly, then for any $\epsilon<1$ there exists some $N(\epsilon)$ such that for all $n>N(\epsilon)$ and all $x$ you have $$| f_n(x) -0 | < \epsilon $$ 
Now if you choose $ n_0 > N(\epsilon)$ then  $f_{n_0}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n_0}}) =1$ contradicting the inequality, hence $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ does not converge uniformly.

Answer (score 0):

Pointwise convergence definition says that for any $\varepsilon >0$ find a natural number $N=N(x,\varepsilon)$. Actually you have almost finished:
For a given $\varepsilon>0$ you must have
 $\frac {nx^2}{n^2x^4+1}\leq\frac {2nx^2}{n^2x^4}= \frac {2}{nx^2}\leq\varepsilon $ and thus $\frac {2}{\varepsilon x^2}\leq n$. Now you can take $N$ to be the integral part of $\frac {2}{\varepsilon x^2}$ so that $n\geq N$. For the part of niform convergence $f_n(x)$ have maximum velue for all $x$ which occurs at the critical point (which is $x=1/\sqrt{n}$)(I am not quite sure check please). At this point $f_n(x)$ converges insinity as $n\rightarrow\infty$. However, if you use formal definition you can show that $f_n(x)\geq \varepsilon_0$ for a particular $\varepsilon_0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "to be the integral part of $\frac 2 {\epsilon x^2}$ ?@daulomb Shouldn't be fine if I take $N=\frac 2 {\epsilon x^2}$

Comment: I meant integer  part but you can take an integer $N$ such that $N\geq\frac{2}{\varepsilon x^2}$.

Comment: @Leyla Alkan: In the case of equality, $N$ may  not be an integer, e.g. if $\varepsilon=1$ and $x=2$.